# How to get the last inserted ID and insert it to the second table using the laravel collection?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

this is the first time I encounter of this problem and to be honest I don't know what this called. I have module where I need to insert all the data in the first table, then every id that inserted to the first table I want to get it each then insert it to the second table. The purpose of inserting the id to the second table is for the relation of the tables. Now I used laravel for my backend and I used the transform method to insert each data.

**Now the main problem here is how can I get each last inserted Id to the first table and Insert it to the second table.**

Here is my data that I inserted to the first table:

```
$collection = $rows->transform(function($item) use ($start,$cash_amount, $bank_deposit_amount, $off_set_amount, $grand_total) {
        
        unset($item["key"]);
        
        $item["checkDate"] = ($item["checkDate"] != '') ? $item["checkDate"] : null;
        $item['encoded_by'] = ($item['customer'] != '') ? Auth::user()->name : '';
        $item['receive_date'] = ($item['customer'] != '') ? $start : null;
        $item['status'] = ($item['customer'] != '') ? "exchange_check" : '';
        $item['amount'] = ($item['amount'] != '') ? floatval(preg_replace('/[^\d.]/', '', $item['amount'])) : '';
        $item["original_date"] = $item["checkDate"];
        $item['cash'] = $cash_amount;
        $item['bank_deposit'] = $bank_deposit_amount;
        $item['offset'] = $off_set_amount;
        $item['grand_total'] = $grand_total;

        return $item;
    });
    
    ExchangeCheck::insert($collection->toArray());
```

For second table I used this model use `App\ExchangeList;` where this model use to inserted all the ID's from the the ExchangeCheck Model:

Is this possible that I can insert each ID's of ExchangeCheck to the ExchangeList?

Thanks.

Comment: What type of relation is between these models? and also what are fields of `App\ExchangeList` ?

Comment: You also might want to use a transaction if you want these statements to be bound (either pass together or fail together).

Answer (score 0):

When inserting your data into your table, instead of `insert` used `insertGetId`, and inject the result into a variable in order to retrieve the `id`.

Try something like :

```
$lastIDinserted = ExchangeCheck::insertGetId($collection->toArray());
```

Otherwise you can use this method :

```
$lastIDinserted2 = ExchangeCheck::select('id')->orderByDesc('id')->first();
// OR
$lastIDinserted2 = ExchangeCheck::latest('id')->first();
```

And to retrieve your `id`, do:

```
$lastIDinserted2 = $lastIDinserted2->id;
```

Hope this helped you !